# Proxy with self signed cert causing hosts to not be found during Docker build?

Tags: docker

I am behind a proxy server with a self signed certificate. I am able to reach docker.io/hub to fetch the latest centos image, but all other hosts seem to be unreachable. I had to set the proxy settings in /etc/sysconfig/docker and drop in the docker.io certificate chain downloaded from the browser into the docker certificate folder to even get that to work. Has anyone heard of this behavior, where all hosts are inaccessible because a proxy server has a self signed certificate? Again, I have set the proxy settings in /etc/sysconfig/docker. I still was unable to reach docker.io to do a docker pull centos until I dropped in the downloaded certificate files to docker.io from a browser to the docker certificate folder. Everything looked fine until I tried doing a build that did a curl statement trying to reach pkg.jenkins-ci.org. That host, and it seems all other hosts, other than the ones I specifically drop certificate chains into the docker certificate folder are unreachable. What can cause this? I have attached an image of a simple "docker build ." with the Dockerfile in the current directory.

[image]

Redhat 7.2 on a virtual machine inside a private network using a proxy with a self signed certificate.

Answer (score 1):

The proxy set in /etc/sysconfig/docker will not propagate to containers iirc. You can pass them into the build via a build argument like so:

```
docker build -t some_image --build-arg HTTP_PROXY=something --build-arg HTTPS_PROXY=something .
```

If you have them set as environment variables on the host you can omit the values, Docker will automatically send them in. Most build args need to be explicitly referenced in the Dockerfile but `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` are special cases (amongst a couple of others) that don't.

May need to copy the cert into the container (or mount `-v`) to make it available to `curl` as well.

Comment: Unfortunately I have tried every combination of putting the proxy settings in the container and Dockerfile as well. I did try: docker build --build-arg HTTP_PROXY="http://username:password@proxy.ourproxy.rtg:9090" --build-arg HTTPS_PROXY="http://password:username@proxy.ourproxy.rtg:9090" .  and I get the same timeout.